# Approximate Identity

Tags: convolution

Let  ${({\varphi}_{n}})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ an Approximate Identity in [Schwartz Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). 
  Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Is it true or not the following statement?
\begin{equation}
\lim _{ n\longrightarrow \infty  }{ \int _{ \mathbb{R} }^{  }{ { \left| y \right|  }^{ \alpha  }\left| { \varphi  }_{ n }\left( y \right)  \right|  }  } dy=0.
\end{equation}

Comment: This is a more general question than the last that I made. I've done the proof with the classical examples of approximate identity but I cannot make a formal proof for whatever approximate identity.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false.  Let $\psi:\mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$ be a smooth function supported on $[-1,1]$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R} \psi = 1$, and suppose $s > 0$.  Define
$$ \varphi_n(x) = n (1-n^{-s}) \psi(nx) + n^{-s} \psi(x-n-1) .$$
It is easily seen to be an approximate identity.  But
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} |y|^\alpha |\varphi_n(y)| \, dy
   \ge \int_{n}^{n+2}  y^\alpha n^{-s} \psi(y-n-1) \, dy
   \ge n^{-s} n^\alpha ,$$
and this diverges if $\alpha > s$.